# Reducing performance impact of search query in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I would like to ask whether my approach to reduce the performance impact that my wildcard query has is appropriate - or if a better approach exists.
I have to perform a "wildcard-on-both-ends" type query in RavenDB, and I have come up with this:

```
currentSession.query(XYZ.class, Query.index(indexToBeQueried))
                                .whereEquals("ID", id)
                                .andAlso()
                                .search("NAME", "*"+Name+"*");
```

My assumption is that RavenDB first reduces the results to be searched by selecting all documents that match the ID field *first*, **then** proceeding to perform the costly search on the remaining result set.
Is this assumption correct ? Does RavenDB work "sequentially" in this case or do I need to do this differently ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. Both portions of the query are evaluated and then union-ed to find the final set of results.

You are better off using full text search, instead of a query like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean I should use your NGram analyser ? Also, would the query remain the same ? (Using the wildcards ?) Is it as simple as adding the analyzed "flag" to the index ? Thanks for a quick clarification !